# How to watch chrome history of my friend, who is logged in from my gmail id?

Tags: gmail, chrome-for-android, history

**What i did** - I have signed in, one of my friend's android phone (its samsung j2) with **my gmail id**.

**What i want** - I want to monitor his phone's youtube and chrome browsing history using **my gmail id**

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations! You are a spy now! what you can do? goto [google.com](https://google.com) & click on search bar & you'll see search history Or just tap on the google search bar on your phone & you'll see last searches.

To get the full activity history [click here: https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity)